# Print either True or False

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Given an array of integers, m=number of moves. Starting from index 0. With each move you can take arr[i] steps either forward or backward. if m becomes 0. and you're at the last position then print true else print false.

For example:
arr contains elements 2,3,1.
m=1;
answer: true;
Explanation: value at i=0 is 2 so, for m=1, take 2 steps forward, you'll reach at end position. So, true.

I tried below code but it is not printing the correct answer:
num_ele is total number of elements in array.

```
bool fun(int arr[],int m,int i,int num_ele)
{
    if(m==0)
    {
        if(i==(num_ele)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    fun(arr,m-1,i+arr[i],num_ele);
    fun(arr,m-1,i-arr[i],num_ele);
}
```

Comment: what is the programming language?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should include work that you have already tried as well as information about what you think is not working and why.

Comment: @CommonMan any, even a pseudo code would help.

Comment: @TimKlein I have edited my code.

Comment: The implementation doesn't use the return values of the recursive calls.

Comment: Is your goal to find a path s.t. you can print true? Is your goal to print the number of true and false paths? In either case, I'd view this as a directed graph (nodes are elts of the array and each node has arcs out to the nodes reachable based on the node value.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is equivalent to the problem of determining whether a deterministic finite automaton over a binary alphabet accepts a string of length m. To construct the automaton, add as many states as elements of the array, and two transitions to represent moving left or right by the corresponding number of positions. Make the state corresponding to the last array element accepting and make the state corresponding to the first array element the initial state.

Next, construct a deterministic finite automaton that accepts all binary strings of length exactly n. This DFA will have n+1 states, one initial state, and one accepting state.

Next, construct a DFA for the intersection of these DFAs' languages using the Cartesian Product Machine construction. This DFA will have one state for every pair of states from the two above DFAs, will start in the state corresponding to the pair of initial states, and will terminate in the state corresponding to the pair of accepting states.

Finally, determine whether the language of this DFA is the empty language or not. A breadth-first or depth-first search, or minimization followed by comparison to the DFA for the empty language, will suffice.

You start with two DFAs having n and n+1 states; construct a DFA with n(n+1) states; and then see whether it accepts strings. The complexity should be O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

The implementation could be done as follows, using C# syntax.

```
bool fun(int[] arr, int m, int i)
{
    if (0 == m)            // base case - if no moves are left, decide
    {                      // whether the end of the array is reached
        return i == arr.Length-1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        int LeftPos = i+arr[i];
        int RightPos = i-arr[i];
        bool ResultLeft = 0 <= LeftPos
                       && LeftPos =< arr.Length-1
                       && fun(arr, m-1, LeftPos);
        bool ResultRight = 0 <= RightPos
                        && RightPos =< arr.Length-1
                        && fun(arr, m-1, RightPos);
        return ResultLeft || ResultRight;
    }
}
```

The implementation does some boundary checking to inspect whether the resulting position would still be inside of the array. Note that it is possible to shortcut the evaluation; if one of the recursive calls returns `true`, evaluation of the other call would not be necessarry. That being said, the index check could be done first in the call; consequently, the implementation would benefet from the shortuct behaviour of the `||` operator as follows.

```
bool fun(int[] arr, int m, int i)
{
    if (i < 0 || i > arr.Length-1) // index checking
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
      if (0 == m)            // base case - if no moves are left, decide
      {                      // whether the end of the array is reached
          return i == arr.Length-1 ;
      }
      else                   // compund case - decide whether moving left
      {                      // or right yields the end position
          return fun(arr, m-1, i+arr[i]) || fun(arr, m-1, i-arr[i]);
      }
    }
}
```